# How can I read properties file through FileInputStream in java (ubuntu)

Tags: java, io, filesystems

```
public static final String propFile =".//src//config//config.properties";
try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(propFile);
        prop.load(inputStream);

        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup(prop.getProperty("jndi.name"));
        conn = ds.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am unable to read from the properties file. It says no such directory, but i have the file in the exact location.

Comment: Make propFile as `"..//src//config//config.properties";`

Comment: Hi Naven thanks for the concern, but still the same error persists.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../src/config/config.properties (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)

Comment: Once right click on file and view the properties. i think file name is `config.properties.properties`

Comment: I cross checked it's "config.properties" only.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `propFile` variable to the absolute path of the `'config.properties'` file in your system.

If it works, then you have a problem with the relative path specified.

Comment: with absolute path it works fine, I have a problem with relative path which I am unable to resolve.

Comment: In your terminal, first navigate to the file containing this source code , and run the 'pwd' command. Then navigate to the folder containing config.properties, and run 'pwd' there too. Then post BOTH the paths here.

Comment: file location containing the above code : 
/home/abs65/workspace/ProductPOC/src/com/abs/util

file location containing the config file :
/home/abs65/workspace/ProductPOC/src/config

Comment: Try propFile="../../../config/config.properties"